# App shows old version of App icon after installing new version of App with new App icon

Tags: ios, ios7, app-store

I am facing very strange issue in iOS 7.1.1.

I had an App at Apple store with version 1.0 with different App icon than version 2.0. Now I have version 2.0 of the same App with different App icon.

Now if I don't have version 1.0 on device and download the version 2.0 of App then there is no issue at all.

But if I have older version 1.0 and I update the app from iTunes then I can see old app icon that was for 1.0 instead of version 2.0 . When I open the app and minimize the app by pressing home button at that time it shows old app icon for 0.5 seconds like a flash and replaced with new icon that is for version 2.0 .

Also if I delete the app and restall it then there is no issue !

I am not understanding whats going on why it shows old app icon ? I have all the App icon images in project for iOS 7.

> Forgot to mention that app version 1.0 was developed by another
>   software firm and I have transferred the version 1.0 into my developer
>   account and I made version 2.0 of the same app with all new code and without old code reference.

But I think this doesn't make sense as I am having all new code for version 2.0 than version 1.0 . Still confused with this issue.

Any guide/suggestions will be helpful for me.

Thanks

Comment: This maybe a stupid question from me but have you absolutely verified all the files with "Icon" in their name are indeed new versions of the icon? Could be that the folder you've set aside for the icons does indeed have the right icons, but there could be a ghost icon somewhere else in the project that is still getting bundled as a resource.

Comment: Does this also happen if, say you have 1.0 installed on the device, and then "install" 2.0 by running from XCode instead of downloading from the App Store. If it happens from XCode too, you can be sure the issue is from your project file and not an App Store/Apple quirk. Checking for the presence of similarly named files, removing them, then removing all resources and adding them to the project again might help.

Comment: @DevKanchen : I have checked this test case via Xcode. There is no issue with this !

Comment: Sorry for multiple posts but I just had another thought - it could be that you bundled a specific version of the icon in 1.0, which you have NOT included in 2.0. I don't remember App Store icon-naming conventions, but let's say you have Icon-res1.png and Icon-res2.png in version 1.0 and then in 2.0 you are only including Icon-res1.png (having removed/deleted Icon-res2) perhaps Springboard on iOS is caching Icon-res2.png and since it hasn't been replaced in 2.0, it is still using the old version. Just a theory, but I'll wait for your thought.

Comment: @DevKanchen: Please see my edited question. Sorry I forgot to mention that thing.

Comment: Then missing icon files might be the thing. You could probably test it by using a dummy image, resize it to all the prescribed sizes for the App Store -https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html - and bundle them in a test/dummy app. Run it a few times on the device through various scenarios (using the multi-tasking screen, open, close multiple times etc to allow for Spotlight to cache the icons). Then remove all the old icons, include YOUR new ones (only the sizes you've actually used in the App Store) and run again.

Comment: Note: It is a bit of a long procedure to test the hypotheses, but unfortunately might be the only way, or the only way I can think of. Of course if someone comes along who has actually experienced your problem, it could save you a lot of trouble/time. :)

Comment: @DevKanchen: ok I will do. But I don't have code of version 1.0 !

Comment: @DevKanchen: my last try would be send an update to app store. Whats your thought on this ? Do you think it will solved by update ?

Comment: No I mean try testing what I mentioned with a dummy app first on a device (probably not on Simulator), using dummy icons of all sizes for the fake v1.0 and then your actual icons with the actual sizes for fake v2.0. If we are able to recreate the problem that way we can be sure this IS in fact the problem.

Comment: @DevKanchen: I am not sure whether version 1.0 included iOS 7 required icon images or not. Could this be a problem ?

Comment: @DevKanchen: I did test as you mentioned above steps and also I've install dummy app as version 1.0 without iOS 7 required app icons and update it from app store with version 2.0 that has all the required iOS 7 app icon images but I am not facing this issue !

Comment: @DevKanchen : issue solve after restarting the device ! I know its strange. Anyways thanks for your efforts and time. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer is also strange like Question.

I just restart the device and issue gone !!! I don't know why but its solved. I know this is not a solution I think its an iOS bug.

Comment: Congratulations! Would still be satisfying to know the outcome of the test though. Just to reiterate/be clear, here's what I meant: 1. Create a dummy app with a new bundle id, different from your App Store thing. 2. Embed in it dummy icons of ALL sizes recommended by Apple, regardless of the devices you are actually supporting. 3. Run it on the device via XCode. 4. Now remove all the old icon files from the dummmy project and add your new (actual) icons in, retaining the old (dummy) bundle id. 5. Run THIS project on the device again through XCode and see if the issue happens again. contd...

Comment: Of course the motivation to do this is less now considering the issue is resolved. But someday when you have time perhaps you could update back here with the results. Thanks!

Comment: I have had the same issue. Restarting the phone fixes it.

Comment: One other issue I am seeing is that during installation it still shows old app icon. Not sure if iOS caches that icon and shows during installation.

Comment: It happened to me on latest version of iOS 13.3, and this solution still works. Thanks!

Comment: I was still getting the old app icon on the App Switcher view on iOS 14.4.1. Again, restarting the device fixed it. Thanks!