# iOS app icon changes between the old and new one after upgrade

Tags: ios, icons, upgrade

I've changed my app name and icon, after upgrading it on some of the devices (with iOS 8.0.2, and iOS 8.1), when moving the app to the background and getting it up back by tapping the app icon it shows the old icon for just a millisecond and then the new one again (kind of jumps between the icons).
(verified that the old icons are deleted in the app itself.)

Googled it but could not find anything :/

Does anyone encountered this? any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to hard clean your project by pressing Cmd + alt + shift + K ?

Comment: I upgrade it from testflight, it's not installed from Xcode

Comment: I've just noticed that it happens only if I first install my app from AppStore, then upgrade with build from TestFlight.

Comment: Maulik answered this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525442/app-shows-old-version-of-app-icon-after-installing-new-version-of-app-with-new-a

Comment: Thanks, btw, if I'm not mistaken in iPhone 6/6+ changing the display zoom also fixes this issue