# Updated ios App from the Apple App Store, but my app is still showing the old version

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, react-native-code-push

I have a version 0.6.5 of my app installed on my Phone.

I release a 0.6.8 version of my app to the Apple App Store, pass the review and the status is changed to "Ready For Sale"

I go to the App Store, search for my app, I see the new updated is listed.

I press the "Update" button, and wait.

However after the update finished installing, I open the app and still the 0.6.5 version.

I go back to the App Store, and I see the "Open" button instead of the "Update" button.

I have to uninstall the app. Go back to the App Store, reinstall again, and now I have the 0.6.8 version.

This problem is affecting a lot of my users. I am not sure how to approach the problem. Does anyone have a solution for this? I will try to report this problem to Apple.

My App is built with react-native and I'm using react-native-code-push in case this is relevant.

Comment: I think you should contact with Apple's Supporter. Because of your app is successfully updated to the AppStore, nothing wrong with the new user except old user can't update app.

Comment: I got a fix by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24531578/6606831) strange answer

Comment: yeah, but as a developer, I cannot tell all my users to restart their phone after they update the app. I have sent a message to Apple, waiting for their response.

Comment: @han4wluc did apple fix your issue? I am facing the same right now